# Rank column in Power BI that change dynamically

Tags: powerbi, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-custom-visuals

Trying to create Organization Chart using **custom visuals** in Power BI Desktop, the requirement is to show chart with filtered data which applies by **Slicer** on department column.

I struck with the limitation of custom visual (which logical), to get proper chart in visual, data-set must have a Root Node, In my scenario `ReportsTo` column should be `null` to identify as root node.

Managed to make `Reportsto` column `null` in each department within SQL view using `ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY EmpDepartment Order by EmpGrade desc` and `CASE` logic. But this already processed data, i'm looking for something during filter selection, so that when user select 2 departments in slicer custom visual won't crash.

I tried following DAX in Power BI desktop to get the RANK based on `Grade` with filtered data, Unfortunately, the **DAX** work as **Measure** not as **Calculated Column**, and With the measure i'm unable to get **expected result** when tried a calculated column using `IF([RANK]=1,BLANK(), ('Table'[ReportsTo]))`

*Note: Index column added in Power BI Desktop - Edit Queries page*

```
RANK = 
MINX (
    FILTER (
        SELECTCOLUMNS (
            ALLSELECTED ('Table'),
            "index", 'Table'[Index],
            "rank", RANKX ( ALLSELECTED ( 'Table' ), 'Table'[Grade],, DESC, DENSE )
        ),
        [index] = MAX ( 'Table'[Index] )
    ),
    [rank]
    )
)
```

Here is sample data, as per following table when department filtered with **IT** (by slicer), `EmpID` **107** would be Root Node based on `ReportsTo_2` column. But visual won't work when 2 departments selected.

```
+-----------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+--------------+
| EmpID     | ReportsTo  | Grade | EmpDepartment | EmpName | ReportsTo_2
+-----------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+--------------+
| 101       | 107        | A1    | IT            | Emp1    | 107         
| 102       | 107        | A1    | IT            | Emp2    | 107        
| 103       | 107        | A1    | IT            | Emp3    | 107        
| 104       | 108        | A2    | Proc.         | Emp1    | 108        
| 105       | 108        | A2    | Proc.         | Emp1    | 108        
| 106       | 108        | A2    | Proc.         | Emp1    | 108        
| 107       | 109        | B1    |  IT           | Mgr1    |
| 108       | 109        | B1    | Proc.         | Mgr2    |
| 109       | 110        | C2    | Management    | Director|
| 110       |            | D9    | Sr.Management | CEO     |
+-----------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+--------------+
```

**Expected Result:** My idea is to get `null` value in `ReportsTo_2` column for highest `Grade` within filtered data (filter by department).

Appreciated your advise to achieve this. Thanks

**Additional info for clarification as requested in comments**

Using following visuals:
[Custom Visual 1](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104381333?tab=Overview)
[Custom Visual 2](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104381630?src=office&tab=Overview)

Scenarios:

1. When filtered with multiple departments (No Root Node available), if i use `ReportsTo_2` as parent it show the error "multiple Root Nodes": [Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSz8N.jpg)
2. When NO filter applied in departments: [Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5J7x.jpg)

Same Scenarios with Custom Visual 2:

1. [Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8njo.jpg)
2. [Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXZFK.jpg)

**Additional Note 2:**
Main issue where i struck with, as **Measure** we can easily get expected result, but as **Calculated Column** same expression doesn't give expected result.
[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUpMS.jpg)

Comment: Measures can work dynamically, calculated columns not. So you say the visual crashes, is that not your real problem?

Comment: I agree, but in this case I don't think so, as long as the filtered data-set has root node the visual works. It this point i'm not looking forward to a fix in visual.

Comment: Can you show what would be your desired result if both the IT and Proc. departments are selected? I'm unable to derive it not knowing the visual you are trying to use. Sounds like a solvable problem though.

Comment: Did you try this on measure:
RANKX ( ALLSELECTED ( Table ), Table[Grade],, DESC, DENSE )
Columns can't be dynamic. You can use a measure like this on a visualization like table to simulate a column.

Comment: Dear @Nacho I already tried this, but that would give me the RANK based on entire  table, requirement is to get the RAN for only filtered data, and use the RANK to in IF condition to replace highest grade to null

Comment: Dear @JelleHoekstra, I have been added additional details along with screenshots, kindly have a look at my edited post. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your problem, the measure your need is below. However please note the limitations of your visuals. They both explicitly need one starting node. Multiple or no starting nodes are not allowed. So even with this measure, selecting both the IT and Proc. in your filter will result in an error as it gives both visuals two possible starting nodes. This measure will solve the problem of having no starting node as it will always result in at least one blank value in your ReportsTo_2.

You can replace the "" with BLANK() when this is explicitly needed, I didn't test it on the visuals.

```
ReportsTo_2 =

var _highestSelectedRank = CALCULATE( MAX ( 'Table'[Grade] ) ; ALLSELECTED( 'Table' ) )

RETURN
    IF (
        MAX( 'Table'[Grade] ) = _highestSelectedRank ;
        "" ;
        MAX ( 'Table'[ReportsTo] )
    )
```

**Update based on comments:** Or forcing the measure to behave like a calculated column

```
ReportsTo_2 =

var _highestSelectedRank = CALCULATE( MAX ( 'Table'[Grade] ) ; ALLSELECTED( 'Table' ) )

RETURN
    MAXX (
        'Table' ; 
        IF (
            'Table'[Grade] = _highestSelectedRank ;
            "" ;
            'Table'[ReportsTo]
        )
    )
```

Comment: I think the aim of this expression to get similar result which i'm getting with **ReportsTo_2 = IF([RANK] = 1, BLANK(), MAX('Table'[ReportsTo]))**. unfortunately, measure wouldn't help in my case, kindly have a look at edited post. Thanks!

Comment: It is impossible to create a dynamic calculated column as @Aldert pointed out before. They get calculated at a refresh and their value is fixed. The only work around that you could try is a measure with forced row context, see my update in a few minutes. If that doesn't work, I'm afraid I can't help you find a solution to your problem.

Comment: Again, the expression work when i added as **Measure**, but doesn't work when same expression added as **Calculated Column**. I think i have to consider as limitation by custom visual (it could have accepted **measures**), and present this report marking limitation that it only work with Single Department filter which i can easily manage in T-SQL as SQL view  is the actual data source.

Comment: i'm just wondering (correct me if wrong), if we could manage to encode `SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[EmpDepartment])` in side the variable expression, so that variable would be populated with highest grade within filtered data!

Comment: The actual code won't matter, it's the output that causing the problem here. The thing we try to do can only be done in a measure while your visual only accepts calculated columns. If there is no way to change what your visual accepts then the exact thing you are asking for is impossible given these constraints. Did you try running the second version of the above code as a measure and adding it to the visual? It won't run as a calculated column as it is evaluated in a different way.

Comment: Yes, i tried second version as **measure**, but no luck even with that, seems it only accept **columns** or **calculated columns**